# Django - When data from query is actually read

Tags: django

I'm a Django noob so I apologize if this is a stupidly simple question.

Here's the code:

```
try:
    m = Message.objects.get(session=request.session.session_key)
except:
    return {'message_status':'','message_text':''}

current_status = m.status
current_text = m.text

m.delete()
```

I'd expect current_status and current_text to be preserved, but they are not. What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "preserved" supposed to mean?

Comment: Meaning, I'm passing current_status and current_text to the template. If I comment out the m.delete() line, then current_status and current_text are populated, but as is, they're blank.

Comment: please mark as accepted if you like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem, simply perform a slice to make a copy of the string before deleting the object.

```
current_status = m.status[:]
current_text = m.text[:]

m.delete()
```

Edit: edit: Why are you not using django.contrib.messages!?

Comment: This isn't how variables in Python work at all. Even if you delete the object, the local variables still have references to the strings.

Comment: @Daniel i agree if you just deleted the model object the strings would still be accessible, but calling the .delete() method does extra cleanup and gets rid of the underlying data too.

Comment: wierd, when i tried it the first time, this is the behavior i observed. fixed answer, advice still stands on fixing it.